# linux + test dns resolving of hosts/ip's but without to wait a long time

Tags: rhel, dns, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved, nslookup

we want to test , fast as possible the hosts/ip's resolving

for example when we do the following

```
host -a linux1

Trying "linux1.df.com"
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

after `20 sec` the host command return failed

the best approach that we get is by the following ( with timeout of 1 second )

```
nslookup -timeout=1 linux1.df.com
```

but in case of large number of machines ( for example 100 machines )  then it will also take some time

so is it possible to test the resolving on each host/IP with quick way ? ( less then 1 second )

Comment: Please don’t [delete questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/606050/86440) and re-post them.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt sorry for that but I post it on super user  , and delete here the post , but  since not get any comment from super user then I post again here with  some changes

Comment: Right, but you could still have undeleted your existing question, rather than post a new one — that would have restored the comments (including Ipor Sircer’s interesting mention of https://github.com/jdrowell/jdresolve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with a loop and redirect output into a file, we run processes in background...

As a simple solution

```
for i in $(cat hosts.txt); do nslookup $i & done > output.txt
```